# SQL server Cursor not working ... Any ideas?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am creating a simple cursor which fetches all the record from a table and for each record it checks for a condition  in another table and updates the first table.

For this i am using a cursor.

This cursor doesnt seem to work. I checked the records are available. It doesnt seem to get into to cursor at all

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[updatetimecardlineitemsabc]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
AS
  BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      -- Insert statements for procedure here
      SELECT *
      INTO   #tctemp
      FROM   timecardlineitem

      DECLARE @records_size INT
      DECLARE @ctr INT

      SET @ctr=0
      SET @records_size = 0

      DECLARE @Id VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @project VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @consultant VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @ass_cons VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @mondate DATE
      DECLARE @sundate DATE
      DECLARE @acId VARCHAR(30)
      DECLARE @count INT
      DECLARE @ct INT

      PRINT( 'hello' )

      SELECT @ct = COUNT(*)
      FROM   timecardlineitem
      WHERE  assigned_consultant__c IS NULL

      PRINT( '@ct is .....' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), @ct) )

      DECLARE cursor_Timecard_Line_Item CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id,
               project__c,
               consultantId__c,
               assigned_consultant__c,
               MONDAY_DATE__C,
               SUNDAY_DATE__C
        FROM   timecardlineitem
        WHERE  assigned_consultant__c IS NULL

      OPEN cursor_Timecard_Line_Item

      FETCH cursor_Timecard_Line_Item 
      INTO @Id, @project, @consultant, 
           @ass_cons,@mondate, @sundate

      PRINT('@id,@project,@consultant......'+@id+'-----'+@project+'-----'+@ass_cons+
             '-----'+convert(varchar,@mondate)+'-----'+convert(varchar,@sundate))


      WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @acId = ID
            FROM   assignedcons
            WHERE  Project__c = @project
                   AND Contact__c = @consultant
                   AND ( Start_Date__c <= @sundate
                          OR Start_Date__c = NULL )
                   AND ( End_Date__c >= @mondate
                          OR End_Date__c = NULL )

            UPDATE timecardlineitem
            SET    assigned_consultant__c = @acId
            WHERE  id = @Id

            FETCH cursor_Timecard_Line_Item 
            INTO @Id, @project, @consultant,
                 @ass_cons,@mondate, @sundate
        END

      CLOSE cursor_Timecard_Line_Item

      DEALLOCATE cursor_Timecard_Line_Item
  END
```

It just prints hello
@ct is .....483

There are 483 records

It doesnt print the print statements inside the fetch. I know i am doing something very silly. Just not able to identify it

Edit: This is what is needed

---

I have 2 tables

1. timecardlineitem
2. assigned_consultant__c

Here is the structure of timecardlineitem

```
[ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ISDELETED] [varchar](50) NULL,
[NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CREATEDDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CREATEDBYID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LASTMODIFIEDDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
["LASTMODIFIEDBYID"] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SYSTEMMODSTAMP] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LASTACTIVITYDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TIMECARD__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ASSIGNED_CONSULTANT_EXISTS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[FRIDAY_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[FRIDAY_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[MONDAY_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[MONDAY_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT_END_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT_NAME__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT_START_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SATURDAY_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SATURDAY_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[STATUS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SUNDAY_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SUNDAY_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[THURSDAY_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[THURSDAY_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTAL_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TUESDAY_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TUESDAY_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[WEDNESDAY_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[WEDNESDAY_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[BILLABLE_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CLIENT_NAME__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTAL_EXPECTED_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT_TYPE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROFESSIONAL_CHECKBOX__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[UTILIZATION_NO_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[MONDAY_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TUESDAY_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[WEDNESDAY_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[THURSDAY_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[FRIDAY_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SATURDAY_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SUNDAY_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[UTILIZATION_DAY_CHARGE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[UTILIZATION_DAYS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CONSULTANT_NAME__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[BILLING_WEEKLY_TARGET__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[UTILIZATION__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[HOURS_REMAINING_ON_PROJECT__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT_OWNER__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CONSULTANTID__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ASSIGNED_CONSULTANT__C] [varchar](50) NULL
```

Here is the structure of [assignedcons]

```
[ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ISDELETED] [varchar](50) NULL,
[NAME] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CREATEDDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CREATEDBYID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LASTMODIFIEDDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LASTMODIFIEDBYID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SYSTEMMODSTAMP] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LASTACTIVITYDATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CONTACT__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[APPROVING_MANAGER__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[C85_EMAIL_ADDRESS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[C85_PROJECT_LEAD__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CURRENT_STATUS_FORMULA__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CURRENT_STATUS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DAILY_CHARGE_RATE_OF_CONSULTANT__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[END_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LEAVE_STATUS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LEAVE_TYPE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LEAVES_AVAILABLE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[NOTES__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT_ROLE_TITLE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[REMAINING_YEAR_FREE_DAYS_FORMULA__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[REMAINING_YEAR_FREE_DAYS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[START_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTAL_LEAVES_APPLIED__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTAL_PO_VALUE_FOR_CONSULTANT__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[UNIQUE_PARAMETER__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[YEAR_END__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ASSIGNED_DAYS_TO_CONSULTANT__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CONSULTANT_DAY_COST__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[MARGIN_ACHIEVED__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[OVERTIME_ALLOWED__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CLIENT_NAME__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[SUB_TOTAL__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[BILLABLE_HOURS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CONSULTANT_DAY_COST_STAMPED__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTAL_HOURS_BOOKED_APPROVED__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LAST_TIMECARD_DATE__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTAL_CHARGES_INCURRED__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DAYS_APPROVED__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[STATUS__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ID_WITH_LINK__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TOTAL_HOURS_REMAINING_ON_PROJECT__C] [varchar](50) NULL,
[NOMINAL_CODE__C] [varchar](50) NULL
```

There are few records  in timecardlineitem which have null values in field called ASSIGNED_CONSULTANT__C

For those records which have null value i need to search for the id in assignedcons
ie I will need to get the first record from timecardlineitem, search in assignedcons which has the project and consultant id same and its start date is <=SUNDAY_DATE__C and enddate is >=MONDAY_DATE__C

```
            SELECT  ID
            FROM   assignedcons
            WHERE  Project__c = @project // @project is the project__c from timecardlineitem 
                   AND Contact__c = @consultant // @consultant is the CONSULTANTID__C from timecardlineitem 
                   AND ( Start_Date__c <= @sundate //@sundate  is the SUNDAY_DATE__C from timecardlineitem 
                          OR Start_Date__c = NULL )
                   AND ( End_Date__c >= @mondate //@sundate  is the monday_DATE__C from timecardlineitem 
                          OR End_Date__c = NULL )

ID  ASSIGNED_CONSULTANT__C  project__c   CONSULTANTID__C SUNDAY_DATE__C  monday_DATE__C
1         null                pjA          CS1             16-Oct-2011    09-oct-2011
2         null                pjB          CS2            16-Oct-2011     09-oct-2011


 Assigned consultant   project__c   Contact__c       startDate      Enddate  
 AC-001        CS1          pjA          cs1         09-oct-2011   16-oct-2011
```

The ASSIGNED_CONSULTANT__C should hold AC-001 for timecardlineitem with id 1

Comment: I doubt you need a cursor here. If you tell us what the purpose of the code is supposed to be with example data I'm sure someone will be able to tell you how to do it properly.

Comment: I agree with Martins comment, but just to help you with the problem, could you verify that the SELECT inside the cursor actually return anything.

Comment: edited the question to include the exact requirement as requested by martin and Arkain

Comment: @Arkain the problem is that its not getting into the statements after the fetch itself. The print statements after the fetch dont get executed...

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what is trying to be accomplished, but if you want it to print for every fetch, you'll need to put the print statement inside the while loop, which it currently is not.

Comment: @FactorMystic if you look at the bottom of the question where i have explained the requirement with example.. i thought of doing it using cursors.. martin and Arkain feel this could be done without using cursors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit TLDR but I think you just need either `UPDATE...FROM`

```
UPDATE t
SET    t.assigned_consultant__c = a.ID
FROM   timecardlineitem t
       JOIN assignedcons a
         ON a.Project__c = t.project__c
            AND a.Contact__c = t.consultantId__c
            AND ( a.Start_Date__c <= t.SUNDAY_DATE__C
                   OR a.Start_Date__c IS NULL )
            AND ( a.End_Date__c >= t.MONDAY_DATE__C
                   OR a.End_Date__c IS NULL )
```

Or, using a correlated sub query

```
UPDATE timecardlineitem
SET    assigned_consultant__c = (SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
                                 FROM   assignedcons a
                                 WHERE  a.Project__c = t.project__c
                                        AND a.Contact__c = t.consultantId__c
                                        AND ( a.Start_Date__c <=
                                              t.SUNDAY_DATE__C
                                               OR a.Start_Date__c IS NULL )
                                        AND ( a.End_Date__c >= t.MONDAY_DATE__C
                                               OR a.End_Date__c IS NULL ))
```

The advantage of the second one is that if the `JOIN` returns more than one possible `ID` an error will be raised instead of getting an indeterminate result.

Comment: the second query is throwing an error                  Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 The multi-part identifier "t.project__c" could not be bound.

Comment: @Prady - Replace all instances of `t.` with `timecardlineitem.`